# Number patterns of fractions

Tags: arithmetic

I can't seem to find a difference for this  number pattern ..

Given a sequence ...

$1,  2/3 , 4/7 , 8/15 , 16/31 ... $

What is the next term of the sequence ?

I can't seem to spot a difference between them .. Anyone else can ? Thanks for the help !

Comment: Try computing the reciprocals.

Comment: Look at the numerators and denominators separately. Can you see the patterns?

Answer (score 1):

For any given fraction in the sequence:

The numerator is the previous denominator +1.

The denominator is 2 times the previous denominator + 1.

Comment: Of course, the first term can be written as $1/1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left \{ \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n}-1} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$